# Implementing multiple countdowns with javascript on Google app engine

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to implement an application on Google app engine, which has multiple countdown timers.

I wonder how to refresh all the counters

```
{% for counter in counters %}
    <table class="countdown">
         <tr class="countdown_amount" align="center">
            <td width="25%" valign="bottom" id="day"></td>
            <td width="25%" valign="bottom" id="hour"></td>
            <td width="25%" valign="bottom" id="minute"></td>
            <td width="25%" valign="bottom" id="second"></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

and there is javascript function to update the `<td>`

Since there are a lot of events, the deadline are stored in counter.date, how can i pass this to javascript?

//////////
Another way I can think about is using the javascript inside the html

```
{% for event in events %}

     var a = parseFloat("{{ event.second }}") * 1000
     var endtime = new Date(a)
     setInterval( function(endtime){
                    var nowtime = new Date()
                    var leftsecond=parseInt((endtime.getTime()-nowtime.getTime())/1000)
                    d=parseInt(leftsecond/3600/24)
                    h=parseInt((leftsecond/3600)%24)
                    m=parseInt((leftsecond/60)%60)
                    s=parseInt(leftsecond%60)
                    document.write('<td width=\"25%\" valign=\"bottom\">' + d + '</td>')
                    document.write('<td width=\"25%\" valign=\"bottom\">' + h + '</td>')
                    document.write('<td width=\"25%\" valign=\"bottom\">' + m + '</td>')
                    document.write('<td width=\"25%\" valign=\"bottom\">' + s + '</td>')}, 1000)
```

but of course it doesn't work, are there Other ways to implement multiple countdown timers in django with google app engine?

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` after the DOM has finished loading. (And if possible don't use it before either.) Giving the elements you need to access an id (as in the first example) is good in a general sense, but not in a loop like that because id needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks, but how to handle these ids? Can i use dynamic id in each django loop?

Comment: You would give an id to table and use classes for day, hour, etc. 
You could then get the cells for example with document.querySelectorAll('#table-1 td.hour')

Setting the id in django would be <table id="table-{{ forloop.counter }}" > i think.

Comment: Problem solved, Thanks nnnnnn and Smoe =) very helpful~